# Which versions of Autofac and Autofac.Mvc.5 to use in .Net 4.8

Tags: autofac, .net-4.8

I am upgrading a .Net 4.5.2 project to .Net 4.8. We have the following:
Autofac 4.81
Autofac.Mvc.5 4.02

What version of each should be used for .Net 4.8?

Regards,
Paul